# Reverting a database insertion with log files?

Tags: sql, database, logging, transactions

I am working on a program that is supposed to insert hundreds of rows to the database per run.

The problem is that once the inserted data is wrong, how can we recover from that run? Currently I only have a log file (I created the format), which records the raw data get inserted (no metadata nor primary keys). Is there a way we can create a log that database can understand it, and once we want to undo the insertion we feed the database with that log file.

Or, if there is alternative mechanism of undoing an operation from a program, kindly let me know, thanks.

Comment: I think the answer is in your tag set `transactions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact, that this is only hundreds of rows, makes it succeptible to the great-grandmother of all undo mechanisms:

- have a table `importruns` with a row for each run you do. I assume it has an integer auto-increment PK
- add a field to your data table, that identifies carries the PK of the import run
- for insert-only runs, you just need to `DELETE FROM sometable WHERE importid=$whatever`

If you also have replace/update imports, go one step further

- for each data table have a corresponding table, that has one field more: `superseededby`
- for each row you update/replace, place an original copy of the row in this table plus the import id in `superseededby`
- to revert, you now have to add `INSERT INTO originaltable SELECT * FROM superseededtable WHERE superseededby=$whatever`

You can clean up `superseededtable` for known-good imports, to make sure, storage doesn't grow unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. Depending on when you notice the error.
If you know there is an error with the data, the you can use the transactions API to rollback to changes of the current transaction.

In case you know there was an error only later, then you can create your own log. Make an index identifying the transaction, and add a field to the relevant table where that id would be inserted. This would allow you to identify exactly which transaction it came from. You can also create a stored procedure that deletes rows according to the given transaction id.